# Self Cooling Solar Powered Bottle

Tags: science-based

If the glass of a bottle is infused with solar cells and micro-technology compressors.  What other chemicals besides freon and ammonia would be less toxic?

Comment: Such a bottle would need a radiator to dissipate the heat, maybe even electric fan.

Comment: Is this really a worldbuilding question?

Comment: If it can work in a small form factor like a bottle, imagine large scale uses.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt Self-cooling glass seems to fall under the heading of "[c]reation of elements of a world," thus making this [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We often permit questions about theoretical devices; I don't see this as being any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much easier with the "Saharan flask" a normal bottle covered with something absorbing (usually rough cloth) soaked with water and left in broad sunlight. Water evaporation cools bottle content.

If You really want to go technological You need solar cells to provide power, some way (e.g.: [Peltier effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_cooling)) to extract heat and some radiant fins to dispose of it.

Note: You don't "infuse" solar cells in anything, you can "place" them arount someth. or "etch" them on someth. surface.

Comment: Along the same lines as the saharan flask, the original "self-cooling solar powered bottle" was a bottle of porous, bisque-fired clay.  The water would, very very slowly, seep out the pores, and produce evaporative cooling - this way, the bottle would self-cool as long as it had water and a warm environment (like sunlight).  Minor bonus over the saharan flask in that you don't need to re-douse the covering, minor negative in that it will keep slowly dripping away.